# i want to write in textbox if it is display on page and click on next button if it is not display on the page then directly click on next button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
if(!driver.findElement(By.id("pt1:r1:0:r1:2:r1:0:it1::content")).isEnabled())
{   
    System.out.println("IS NOT DISPLAYED"); // if text box is display
    driver.findElement(By.id("pt1:r1:0:r1:2:next")).click();
}
else if(driver.findElement(By.id("pt1:r1:0:r1:2:r1:0:it1::content")).isEnabled())
{           
    System.out.println("IS DISPLAYED"); // if text box is not display
    driver.findElement(By.id("pt1:r1:0:r1:2:r1:0:it1::content")).sendkey("ABCXYZ");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pt1:r1:0:r1:2:next")).click();
}
```

I have tried with try and catch block its working but it takes time to execute script.

Comment: I don't really understand what it is you're asking for help with. Does the above code give you any errors? Where did you try inserting try/catch and did that provide any information or clues on what might be wrong?

Comment: he is saying that above code is working fine but taking too much time. asking for better solution or some modification in code to enhance its performance

Answer (score 0):

Simply explained, what you want to do is:
1. check if the textbox exists on the page... if it exists, put text in it.
2. click the next button.

Whether or not the checkbox exists, you still click on the next button so pull that outside your `if`.

```
List<WebElement> textboxes = driver.findElements(By.id("pt1:r1:0:r1:2:r1:0:it1::content"));
if (!textboxes.isEmpty())
{
    // textbox exists
    textboxes.get(0).sendKeys("ABCXYZ");
}

driver.findElement(By.id("pt1:r1:0:r1:2:next")).click();
```

If you are going to reuse the locators (`By`s), I would suggest that you store them in a variable, e.g.

```
By nextButtonLocator = By.id("pt1:r1:0:r1:2:next");
driver.findElement(nextButtonLocator).click();
```

I would suggest that you read some tutorials on Java programming to improve your programming knowledge. There are some really good Java books you can get also.